# Connecting Javafx Apps to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, jdbc, javafx, phpmyadmin

im trying to use phpMyAdmin as DB on my javafx apps but everytime I open my apps, no data are being displayed and there are errors.

This is my Connect class:

```
public java.sql.PreparedStatement connectDatabase() throws Exception{
    java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql6.freemysqlhosting.net/hostingserver:3306","dbUserName","dbPassword");
    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Select ORNUM,AMOUNT from receipt");
    return ps;
}
```

Comment: *"and there are errors"* please add them to your question. This could provide valuable information... Furthermore I assume that query works, if you execute it it in phpmyadmin via "web interface"?

Comment: @fabian that errors were in the output part of the netbeans. recently i was using localhost db. after creating a webhost, i tried to change the url in getConnection(url). do i need to install xampp for this ?

Comment: You need the database to be available at the specified adress. That means `sql6.freemysqlhosting.net/hostingserver` needs to provide access to your database on port `3306`. You can of course install xampp locally, run it and test your database via `localhost` / `127.0.0.1`. And BTW: If there are exceptions printed to the netbeans console, they can provide usefull info about the source of the error... Did you add/load the correct driver (see [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html#jdbcdriver))?

Comment: @fabian yes i think i load the correct driver. how can i provide access to my database port? what im thinking is that, if i deploy my apps to different computers, they'll use the phpMyAdmin (webhost) DB as their DB. so i'm thinking that i will not install any apps as third party in connecting the cloud DB  to my apps (for ex. xammp) and use any possible way so do it using codes in javafx.